# ERR_ICANN_NAME_COLLISION local issue

Tags: macos, proxy, ampps

I'm using OSX and I have been using [AMPPS](https://www.ampps.com/) for my local development environment. Everything was peachy then all of

```
This site can’t be reached

This site on the company, organization or school intranet has the same URL as an external website. 

Try contacting your system administrator.
ERR_ICANN_NAME_COLLISION
```

I've tried to automatic proxy config in network preferences, restarting my computer, restarting chrome etc.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out .dev is top level domain and purchased by google so can't be used even locally...:\

Comment: It can still be used locally if you add the .dev domain to your hosts file, it will route that traffic to your local machine. The issue here is that in addition to purchasing this gTLD they also just released a new Chrome that adds the *.dev and *.foo gTLDs to their list of preloaded HSTS domains which means it needs to be served with an SSL certificate even locally.